# Extand Netbeans RESTful Webservice

Tags: web-services, netbeans, restful-url

i did this tutorial http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html to create a restful webservice with my mysql db.

the basic things works fine, but now i want to extend the service functionality. how can i add additional parameters to the GET service ? 
i tried this 
[image: netbeans restful test]

but as a result I have all cities.
when I add the parameter countryCode links the service becomes
http://localhost:8080/Data/resources/converter.city/?
countryCode=TUR×tamp=1323114935089 
This is my code 
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package service;

```
import converter.City;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

/**
 *
 * @author mehdi
 */
@Stateless
@Path("converter.city")
public class CityFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<City> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "DataPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public CityFacadeREST() {
        super(City.class);
    }

    @POST
    @Override
    @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public void create(City entity) {
        super.create(entity);
    }

    @PUT
    @Override
    @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public void edit(City entity) {
        super.edit(entity);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    public void remove(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        super.remove(super.find(id));
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public City find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        return super.find(id);
    }

    @GET
    @Override
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public List<City> findAll() {
        return super.findAll();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{from}/{to}")
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public List<City> findRange(@PathParam("from") Integer from, @PathParam("to") Integer to) {
        return super.findRange(new int[]{from, to});
    }

    @GET
    @Path("count")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String countREST() {
        return String.valueOf(super.count());
    }

    @java.lang.Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to update the annotations in your Java resource class to accept the additional parameter(s). Have you looked at the annotation support for query parameters in JAX-RS?

Comment: thak you but i don't found where i have to add annotation , i added my code to the post

Comment: Here is documentation of the API, http://wikis.sun.com/display/Jersey/Overview+of+JAX-RS+1.0+Features after you understand how paths work (which will tell you what method to modify), look at the section "Extracting Request Parameters" which will tell you how to get at the request parameters.